# Перенос кода с NASM на MASM

Tags: ассемблер

```
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h  ; Boot signature
```

Это конец кода NASM загрузочного сектора. Мне надо его реализовать на MASM 6.11. Я делаю что то вроде этого (ставлю метку в конце кода my_end):

```
my_end:
db (7DFEh- (offset my_end)) dup (0)
dw 0AA55h
```

но не компилируется. Кто знает как сделать?